# Intellij plugin development - class not found?

Tags: intellij-idea, plugins

I'm getting a plugin exception when I run the plugin I've developed.

It says:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my/class.name.Here PluginClassLoader[plugins.flashcards, 1.0] com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader@26537aa9
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader.loadClass(PluginClassLoader.java:63)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionManagerImpl.convertStub(ActionManagerImpl.java:140)
    ... 19 more
```

Presumably there is something missing or it's not bundling or something - I'm pretty much using the base build.gradle file and a pretty vanilla plugins.xml file, so I am unsure what is going wrong?

(Also, if someone wanted to make a plugins tutorial i would honestly just pay a lot of money for that right now, the actual documentation is crap!)

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution? (yes agree, the documentation is really bad)

Comment: Must agree here to, documentation is bad and not user-friendly

Answer (score 5):

I can only guess since there is so little information provided but I ran into this exact same issue while following the walkthrough, so I hope I can help.

My issue was the source folder I created my package and class under. While Gradle was using `src/main/kotlin/` as the source directory, I was attempting to create a Java class Action.

Telltale sign was the Gradle output stating that there were no Java files to compile.

Proper way to do this was to create a new folder for `src/main/java/` and recreate my package structure and implement the Java classes I needed.

Problem was mixing Java into a Kotlin source folder. I am new to kotlin, please don't hurt me.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me!  I assume a lot of people would get caught up by this because if you follow the preferred JetBrains method (i.e. using Gradle) this will happen automatically... and then most of their code samples are pure Java not Kotlin, so easy to get caught out.

Answer (score -1):

It is impossible to diagnose setup problems without seeing the actual code.

"the actual documentation is crap" If you have any constructive feedback, you're welcome to submit that as explained here https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/platform_contributions.html